# Amazon S3 - Prevent URL Sharing

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm hosting videos on Amazon S3 and was wondering if anyone here could give me any tips to stop people from finding the direct video URL and sharing it around as well as using it on their website.

I'm using WordPress and I have embedded it into a members only page. However, I'm worried people are going to right-click on the page, find the direct URL and share it around that way.

I'm thinking of disabling right-clicking but was wondering if there was a better way.

Also by going to File-->Save Page As and saving the page, it also downloads the .mp4 video embedded into the website.

Any advice?

Comment: I don't think you can prevent the sharing urls in any way. Sure, you could disable right click, but what about inspect using F12? That's in Chrome, but what about Firefox? What if someone installs extension that can grab any url from your site? Not that easy. You can ask support on Amazon if there is any way to prevent that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CloudFront to access s3 object.
When you hit CloudFront url it access object from s3.
it hides the actual url from user.
You can also generate policy statement for restrict access for particular user.